# Find all real polynomials $f,g$ such that $\forall n\in\Bbb N,\;f(n) = \frac{g(1) + g(2) + \dots + g(n)}{g(n)}$

Tags: polynomials

Question:

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be polynomials such that

$$f(n) = \frac{g(1) + g(2) + \dots + g(n)}{g(n)}$$

for all integers $n \ge 1$.

We want to find all such pairs of polynomials $(f,g)$.

Here is my attempt

WLOG $g$ is monic.

Claim 1: $f(n)=kn+d$

Proof: Define $s(k,n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}k^i$. First we see that $s(k,n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$, because we can then always look at $c\cdot(m+1)^l-c \cdot m^l$ and always choose $c$ like that for each the rate of change matches in the of $s(k,n)$. this implies that $\deg(f)=1$.

Claim 2: Let $k>0$ denote the degree of $g$, then $f(x)=\frac{x}{k+1}+\frac{k}{k+1}$

Since $g$ is monic we get for the leading coeefficient $s(m,n)$ is $\frac{1}{{{k+1}\choose{1}}}=\frac{1}{k+1}$. Furthermore for $n=1$ follows $ f(1)=1$. Hence the claim is proven.

Claim 3: $g(n)=g(1)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k+1+i}{i}\right)$
Induction
Claim 1:
I've shown that $f(n) = kn + d$.

Claim 2:
I've found that $f(x) = \frac{x}{k+1} + \frac{k}{k+1}$.

$f(n)g(n) - f(n-1)g(n-1) = g(n)$

$\left(kn + d\right)g(n) - \left(k(n-1) + d\right)g(n-1) = g(n)$

$kng(n) + dg(n) - k(n-1)g(n-1) - dg(n-1) = g(n)$

$kng(n) + dg(n) - kng(n-1) + kg(n-1) - dg(n-1) = g(n)$

$g(n) \left(kn + d - k(n-1) + k - d\right) = g(n)$

$k(n - n + 1 - 1) + k - d = 1$

$k(0) + k - d = 1$

$k - d = 1$

$k - d = 1$

$k - d = 1$

$d = k - 1$

$f(n) = kn + (k - 1)$

$d = k - 1$

$g(n) = g(1) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k+1+i}{i}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k+1+i}{i}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{kn + k}{i}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k(n+1)}{i}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{k(n+1)}{i}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \left(\frac{k(n+1)}{1}\right) \left(\frac{k(n+1)}{2}\right) \left(\frac{k(n+1)}{3}\right) \ldots \left(\frac{k(n+1)}{n-1}\right)$

$g(n) = g(1) \frac{k(n+1)}{1} \cdot \frac{k(n+1)}{2} \cdot \frac{k(n+1)}{3} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{k(n+1)}{n-1}$

$g(n) = g(1) \cdot \frac{(k(n+1))^n}{(n-1)!}$

The main idea is if you sum a polynomial $G(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} g(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k+a_{k-1}i^{k-1} \cdots a_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(i^n\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(a_{k-1}i^{k-1}\right)\cdots \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(a_0\right)$. but now only the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(i^k\right)$ generates a poynomial of degree $k+1$ so also it is the only one which determines the leading coefficient. if you look at the rate of change of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(i^k\right)$ it is $n^k$, which can only be produced by the highest deree term, so we look at $c\cdot (n+1)^{k+1}-c\cdot n^{k+1}$ the rate of change of the highest degree term. This is by binomial expansion $c\cdot {{k+1}\choose{1}}n^{k}+\cdots$. But $c\cdot {{k+1}\choose{1}}=1$ since else our polynomial does not match the growth of the sum. So $c=\frac{1}{{{k+1}\choose{1}}}=\frac{1}{k+1}$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The question asked for all **pairs** $(f,g)$. Which polynomials can be $g$? All monic polynomials? If not, which ones? You could try checking your work by trying a few examples of $g$ on the right hand side and seeing what you get.

Comment: Your $f(n) = kn + (k-1)$ contradicts your earlier $f(x) = \frac{x}{k+1} + \frac{k}{k+1}$.

Comment: I posted a answer please checkout and why f(n) = kn+(k-1) will contradicts me earlier?

Comment: You have documented your current progress and shown significant efforts to solve your problem, no doubt here. Could you maybe also explain in the question why you're interested in this question? Is it a problem in a homework assignment or did you encounter this problem in your research? If the problem is from a book, a website or any other source, then please also add the source. If you do that, I see no reason why the question should remain closed.  After editing don't forget to check the box that asks you if you want the question reopened :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $f(n) g(n) - f(n-1) g(n-1) = g(n)$, i.e.
$$ (f(n)-1) g(n) = f(n-1) g(n-1) $$

Comment: I edited the answer please check my work

Answer (score 2):

I want to look at the sum $S_k(n)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^k=1+2^k+\cdots+n^k$ for $k\ge 0$ and $n\ge 1$. We only need the limiting behavior, so we avoid Faulhaber's formula and instead use the integral approximation to obtain
$$\frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1}=\int_0^nx^k\mathrm dx\le S_k(n)\le\int_1^{n+1}x^k\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{k+1}\left[(n+1)^{k+1}-1\right].$$
Let $\varepsilon_k(n)$ be the function given by $S_k(n)=(1+\varepsilon_k(n))\frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1}$, then the above shows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\varepsilon_k(n)=0$.

Now, let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^Da_kx^k$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^db_kx^k$ be the two polynomials, i.e. we have
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{g(n)}\sum_{i=0}^ng(n),$$
and we assume wlog that $b_d=1$.
Before we start, notice that we necessarily have $g(n)\neq 0$ for all $n\ge 1$ since otherwise the right hand side is not well-defined (or infinite in absolute, depending on your preference) and hence the equality cannot hold.

First, assume that $d=0$, i.e. $g(x)=b_0=1$ is constant. Then we have
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{g(n)}\sum_{i=1}^ng(i)=\frac{n}{1}=n,$$
so we necessarily have $f(x)=x$ (since there is only one polynomial which agrees with the identity on an infinite number of points, namely the identity).

Now, let $d>0$.
Notice that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^ng(i)&=\sum_{k=0}^db_kS_k(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^db_k(1+\varepsilon_k(n))\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}\\
&=\left(1+\varepsilon_d(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\frac{(1+\varepsilon_k(n))(d+1)b_k}{(k+1)n^{d-k}}\right)\frac{n^{d+1}}{d+1}.
\end{align*}
Let $\varepsilon(n)$ be the function given by $\sum_{i=1}^ng(i)=(1+\varepsilon(n))\frac{n^{d+1}}{d+1}$, then the above shows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\varepsilon(n)=0$.
On the other hand, we have
$$g(n)=\left(1+\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\frac{b_k}{n^{d-k}}\right)n^d,$$
so the function $\delta(n)$ given by $g(n)=(1+\delta(n))n^d$ satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\delta(n)=0$.
But this means that the relative error in the numerator and denominator vanishes and we have
$$f(n)=\frac{(1+\varepsilon(n))\frac{n^{d+1}}{d+1}}{(1+\delta(n))n^d},$$
so the function $\gamma(n)$ given by $f(n)=(1+\gamma(n))\frac{1}{d+1}n$ satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\gamma(n)=0$.
Further, we have
$$1+\gamma(n)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^Da_kn^k}{\frac{1}{d+1}n}=\sum_{k=0}^D(d+1)a_kn^{k-1},$$
which shows that $D=1$ since the left hand side tends to $1$, so the right hand side also has to tend to $1$, but it would be diverging for $D>1$. This also shows that $a_1=\frac{1}{d+1}$, again since the left hand side tends to $1$, and the right hand side tends to $(d+1)a_1$. This shows that $f(x)=\frac{1}{d+1}x+a_0$.

Next, we notice that $f(1)=\frac{g(1)}{g(1)}=1$ on the one hand, and on the other hand $f(1)=\frac{1}{d+1}+a_0$, so we get $a_0=1-\frac{1}{d+1}=\frac{d}{d+1}$.
Hence, with $F_d(x)=\frac{1}{d+1}x+\frac{d}{d+1}$ we have $f=F_d$.

As we already noticed, we have $g(n)f(n)-g(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}g(i)=g(n-1)f(n-1)$.
This gives
$$g(n)=\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)-1}g(n-1)=\frac{\frac{1}{d+1}(n-1)+\frac{d}{d+1}}{\frac{1}{d+1}n+\frac{d}{d+1}-1}g(n-1)=\frac{n-1+d}{n-1}g(n-1)$$
for $n\ge 2$ (using that $f(1)=1$ and that $f$ is increasing, so the denominator is positive). Induction yields
\begin{align*}
g(n)&=\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{k-1+d}{k-1}g(1)
=\frac{(n-1+d)!}{d!(n-1)!}g(1)\\
&=\binom{n-1+d}{d}g(1)=\frac{g(1)}{d!}\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(n-1+d-k).
\end{align*}
For any real $c\neq 0$ and any integer $d>0$ let $G_{c,d}$ be the degree $d$ polynomial given by $G_{c,d}(x)=\frac{c}{d!}\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(x+d-1-k)$. Since $g$ and $G_{g(1),d}$ agree on infinitely many points, we necessarily have $g=G_{g(1),d}$. Since we assumed that $g$ is monic, we must have $c=g(1)=d!$. Notice that the roots of $g$ are $-(d-1),\dots,0$, so we also have $g(n)\neq 0$ for $n\ge 1$. From this proof it is also clear that
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{g(n)}\sum_{i=0}^{n}g(i)$$
indeed holds for all $n\ge 1$.
Notice that we also have $f=F_0$ and $g=G_{1,0}$ for $d=0$ by the above, so in general the desired pairs are
$$\{(F_d,G_{c,d}):d\ge 0,c\neq 0\}$$
over integers $d$ and real numbers $c$.